# Speed Optimization

Tags: magento2

I am working on site speed optimization. I am using Magento2.3.1. I am facing issue related to cache folder is not writable. I gave full permission but still getting cache folder is not writable.My site is working fine but ON Google page speed and Gtmetrix I am facing issue related to cache not writable

[image]

[image]

Please guide me.

Comment: you need to give permission to var folder also and page cache also

Comment: I gave permission to var folder but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your webserver user can't access the directory. You need to change **owner** of your `var` folder.

Try this at root of your magento installation directory :
`sudo chown -R httpuser:httpuser var/`

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed owner of my var folder but still facing issue

Comment: Can you add the result of `ls -ali var/` command ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported with some Specific Operating system versions.

can you post what was your Operating system version or upgrade teh version and check.

In one of the ubuntu version we have faced permission issues and on upgrade of that version we got this sorted.